# Creating a .BAT file and Do Not Know the Name of Some Folders and Drive Names

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am creating a Windows 7 batch file. Its purpose is simple: to install Minecraft to the computer and auto save it every 5 minutes. The way of doing it is  quite hard. Here's how it should work:

1. User inserts USB drive containing: Minecraft data, a bat file, and some sort of file to autorun the bat file.
2. The autorun thing opens the bat file.
3. The bat file copies a folder and its' files from the USB drive, which is at USBDirectoryName:.minecraft to the directory C:\Users\SomeUsername\AppData\Roaming
4. The bat files copy a file called Minecraft.jar to the Downloads folder.
5. The bat files run the Minecraft.jar file.
6. The user uses the Minecraft.jar file to open the actual Minecraft game.
7. The bat file detects that the actual game has opened and starts a timer for 5 minutes.
8. After 5 minutes the program copies the C:\Users\SomeUsername\AppData\Roaming.minecraft\saves\New World to USBDirectoryName:.minecraft\saves
9. The user finishes playing the game and the disconnects the USB drive.
10. When the user wants to play again, the user connects the USB drive and the process starts over again.

Here are the problems with this process:

1. I don't know the directory of the USB drive.
2. I don't know the username of C:\Users\SomeUsername\AppData\ at all.

Here is some helpful for thought about my problem to keep in mind:

That's how it should work. I am making this for my friend who is mentally disabled. He is incapable of launching and installing and doing all the work to get Minecraft running himself. Therefore I help him every day when he goes to the public library to set up and saves the game. It is kind of me to do it myself but I'm not there sometimes and he will still wants to play. That's why I need to make the USB drive for him. Keep in mind that he will not be able to fix any problems or do anything but play the game and click the "Launch" button when it get's to that step.

Comment: Autorun on USB drives has been disabled in Windows since Windows Vista if memory serves me correctly.

Comment: Okay well he can open the bat file himself I'll teach him that much.

Comment: Open up a cmd prompt and type: `set`. You will get a list of all the environmental variables that Windows uses. You should see the ones you need to use.

Comment: there are systemvariables `%user%` (and `%appdata%` and `%localappdata%`, if those help)

Comment: Please note that https://stackoverflow.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: If I understand well, you are coding a BAT script which will be placed into the USB drive, isn't it? When you say that you don't know the directory of the USB drive, what do you mean exactly? The directory which the USB is mapped within **the Windows filesystem** (typically F:), or some directory **within** the USB?

Answer (score 1):

autorun.inf works on windows vista and up (do research into that), the built in variable USERPROFILE returns c:\users[the username of the profile, not actually whats in the brackets]